# how to sh multiple arguments in a single line

Tags: shell

Forgive my naivity. I am very new to this..
Can you please help, I have the following sh file where I would like take in the arguments and execute the sh line

```
********trial.sh file to be executed ******

#!/bin/sh
inputfile1=$1
inputfile2=$2
out=$3

python ldsc.py --rg ./sumstats/$inputfile1,./sumstats/$inputfile2 --ref-ld-chr eur_w_ld_chr/ --w-ld-chr eur_w_ld_chr/ --out ./logfiles/$out.out
```

command line argument

```
sh trial.sh diastolic systolic output.file
```

so that the following line the sh file gets replaced and executed...

```
python ldsc.py --rg ./sumstats/diastolic,./sumstats/systolic --ref-ld-chr eur_w_ld_chr/ --w-ld-chr eur_w_ld_chr/ --out ./logfiles/output.file.out
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is the question? Running `sh trial.sh diastolic systolic output.file` will execute:

```
python ldsc.py --rg ./sumstats/diastolic,./sumstats/systolic --ref-ld-chr eur_w_ld_chr/ --w-ld-chr eur_w_ld_chr/ --out ./logfiles/output.file.out
```

Do you have a file `ldsc.py` in the directory?